# Using next() with block elements in between

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery's `next()` to grab the very next paragraph of the selected element, but because there is a div in the way, it seems as though next will not work.  What selector should I be using instead?

Works :

```
<div>
   <span class="clickme">A name here</span>
   <p class="showme" style="display:none;">Here's some text! </p>
</div>
$('.clickme').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.showme').slideDown();
});
```

Does not work :

```
<div>
   <span class="clickme">A name here</span>
   <div></div>
   <p class="showme" style="display:none;">Here's some text! </p>
</div>
$('.clickme').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.showme').slideDown();
});
```

Why does this occur?  Does `next()` with a specified class not go beyond the very next block element?  Is that why this is happening?  Is there a selector that specify the very 'next' class with `showme` should be selected?

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QespX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.next()`: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

`.nextAll()`:Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

So this is how you go

```
$('.clickme').click(function() { 
    $(this).nextAll('.showme').slideDown();   //as clickme>showme
});
```

More information about [Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) can be found out at jQuery API Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.showme').slideDown();
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QespX/1/**

The only reason this works is because `.showme` is a sibling of `.clickme`. `.nextAll()` will select *all* of the `.showMe` elements after your clicked element, but since you have only one, it'll work.

If that's a problem, you can use `.first()` to narrow the results down:

```
$(this).nextAll('.showme').first().slideDown();
```

Comment: Ahhhh, so if that's the case, could I use `$(this).sibling('.showme')` instead?  Would that be more ideal?

Comment: @RCNeil: There's only `.siblings()`, which is just like `.nextAll()` but it searches in both directions. I don't really know why jQuery's `.next()` doesn't find the next element like you would expect.

Comment: Ah.  Many thanks @Blender!  Actually, since there will be more elements, it actually seems like `siblings()` is a more appropriate selector in this case.  Appreciate the answer!

Comment: p.s. the only reason I marked the other answer is because I like giving rep to the less fortunate.  Your answer really did provide the insight I needed for my code.